# Django not creating tables for my custom user models

Tags: django, model, syncdb

Using Django 1.5, trying out the custom user feature.

I only have 3 models in the project. Here they are,

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
class testModel (models.Model):
```

No errors when I do `python manage.py validate`. When I do `python manage.py sqlall lancer` (lancer is the name of the app), it shows the following,

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "lancer_testmodel" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

What happened to the SQL code for the other two models? Does it only create tables for models that explicitly inherit `models.Model`?

Additional information,

1. I added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'lancer.CustomUser'` at the end of my
   settings.py file per the Django documentation
2. I commented out all the other installed apps in settings.py. I know
   that a lot of them were used by `contrib.auth`, but since I'm using
   a new custom user model, I just commented everything else out.

This is what it looks like now,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'lancer',
)
```

Comment: It's added to your settings the variable `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres yes it is. I added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'lancer.CustomUser' at the end of my settings.py file.

Comment: I think you have in your `INSTALLED_APPS` something like `myapp_where_my_model_is`

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres I have it at the end, 'lancer', that's my app's name. Do I need to include anything beyond that? My testModel seems to work just fine, just the custom user models aren't getting tables created.

Comment: Thik I found solution see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `PermissionsMixin` depends of

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
```

if you  comment only `django.contrib.auth`  and uncomment `django.contrib.contenttypes`,
you will have this error

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
>   users.myuser: 'groups' has an m2m relation with model `<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>`, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
>   users.myuser: 'user_permissions' has an m2m relation with model `<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Permission'>`, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

if you uncomment  `django.contrib.auth` and comment `django.contrib.contenttypes`

You will have this error

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
>   auth.permission: 'content_type' has a relation with model <`class 'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType'>`, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

and if you uncomment the two the sqlall has to generate your table :D

Comment: Thank you. I actually found 1 more critical thing wrong with my code (which I should have posted in full but it was so long...). Since I copied most of the code from Django's existing contrib.auth.AbstractUser, I also copied this piece of code: `class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        abstract = True`, which apparently tells Django that this is not a real model or something, since it has this "abstract=True" thing. After removing that, and the changes you suggested, it worked!! Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah man abstract means ` This model will then not be used to create any database table.` as the doc says (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: This took me so long to figure out! I was trying to add Stormpath to my app and it wasn't mentioned anywhere in their documentation. Thank you!